# Toggle nibbles in a 16 bit register (8086)

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I want to **toggle** (invert) the **most significant nibble**
and the **least significant nibble** of `AX` register. What will be sequence of assembly language instructions for this?

Comment: Have you made an attempt at solving this? Hint, use `XOR`.

Comment: Tried but unable to solve. how to make 1000 1010 1010 0000 to 0111 1010 1010 1111? will XOR work?

Comment: @Yeahia2508 Certainly.  Try `xor ax, 0f00fh`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd strongly suggest reading the manuals for these processors if you're going to be writing any assembly for them. This can be done in a single instruction:

```
XOR AX, 0xF00F
```

Inverting bits is easily done using an [Exclusive or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) with `1` bits. By performing an exclusive or where the upper and lower nibbles of a 16-bit word are set, the bits in those nibbles of `AX` are inverted.

Comment: I don't think lack of reading the manual was the problem here, more likely not understanding what XOR does.  i.e. not understanding / not thinking of `value ^= 0xF00F`, rather than inability to translate it to x86 asm.